# JavaScript & c# - How to check value of hidden element

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

There is (suppose to be) a label or textbox **in hidden mode** that from the code behind will be set (text value) to "user" or "manager".

I want to be able to make a JavaScript verify what is the value of the (hidden) textbox/label when there's a click event on given table row (`<tr>`) which dose not have `runat="server"` property set.

If a client tries to click on that row (actually that row has a few textbox elements) 
so if client try to edit e.g. click on the row 
then action taken by a js function like `alert("no edit allowed")` will be taken.

```
<tr id="TR_editTimein" onClick="javascript:CheckIfManager();">
    <td> <input type="text" id="timeIn" /></td>
</tr>
```

1. If code behind recognize a manager(from `Request.QueryString`) it sets the hidden LBL or TXTBX with value "manager"
2. JavaScript `onClick` event over `TR_editTimein` will trigger `CheckIfManager()`
   function
3. `CheckIfManager()` will ask for the value of the hidden element and if value is "user" it will do alert("no edit option for non Managers")

For now, what happens is if i set that say aspTextBox to `Visible=false`
JavaScript also don't see it.

what is the right way to validate if the client is user or manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `Visible=False`, the ASP.NET control wont even get rendered in browser ( client -side ). That means DOM won't have that object and so you cannot fetch that object using `getElementById`.

The alternative is to use an `asp:HiddenField` which renders as  `input type='hidden'`.

If you have *a resolute and unyielding need* to use `asp:Label` or `asp:TextBox` set the `display:none;` from code-behind like this

```
myLabelID.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
```

That way the object will be rendered in browser and hidden from user allowing you to fetch that using JavaScript.

Comment: sounds like the right plan !! thank u very much Naveen gonna try both (: